# remove question mark from 301 redirect using htaccess when the user enters the old URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I successfully redirected urls like www.example.com/importlist to www.example.com/index.php?importlist.

However i need to do a redirect 301 when the user enters the url www.example.com/index.php?importlist to www.example.com/importlist (to show it in the address bar).

I tried with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.php|web/.*)(.+)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

It works pretty fine, however the question mark remains in the url. which means: when the user enters a url like www.example.com/index.php?importlist it redirects to www.example.com/?importlist.

Ive tried to remove this question mark using rewrite conditions (%{AAAA}) and adding them to the 301 redirect, adding ? at the end, etc, but nothing seems to work and in the worst case it ends up in a redirect loop. Ive also tried all other answers posted in similar question during 2 whole days, and nothing seems to work, so i had to do my own question.

Adittional note: it must work with all pages, not only importlist, example: if the user enters www.example.com/index.php?perso it must redirect 301 to www.example.com/perso, and so with all other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^((?!web/)[^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Hello anub, n tnx 4 ur answer. I tried ur code, however it generates a n internal server error. In the error log, it displays this: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(?!web/)[^/.]+)/?$' any idea of whats wrong with that regex? tnx in advanced.

Comment: sorry there a typo, its fixed now, can you retest?

Comment: Oh, i didnt notice the missing (.

Comment: Oki, so after retest the redirection works fine, however the question mark is still appearing in the address bar http://www.example.com/?importlist. u.u

Comment: Nothing, the question mark still appears. The difference is that now some pages redirects to home, like www.example.com/index.php?perso. it redirects to www.example.com

Comment: :o it works on another browser. What kind of sorcery is that?

Comment: It will work on current browser also but just make sure to clear your browser cache (since we were using 301 that is cached by browsers).

Comment: Oh, tnx a lot anub u saved my life. One last thing, when the user enters www.example.com/index.php it must redirect to www.example.com. Do i add a single 301 to do this? or would that affect your code? :S

Comment: oh, no, with this update now nothing works. It redirects http://www.example.com/index.php?perso to http://www.example.com/index.phpperso (and yes, i cleared all cache)

Comment: ok try updated code now. And use a new browser to test again.

Comment: yay! it is working now :) :D (party). Thx tnx tnx a lot, anub. Ill mark ur question as accepted. U did in some minutes what i couldnt in days. tnx again :P